# Clojure: Define multimethods from list of symbols?

Tags: clojure, multimethod

In a Clojure exercise that I'm working on, I have several multimethods, all of which just use `identity` as the dispatch function. For example:

```
(defmulti amount identity)
(defmulti bottles identity)
(defmulti pronoun identity)
(defmulti action identity)
(defmulti pred identity)
```

Since all of them use the same `identity` function for dispatch, I would like to just iterate over the names and call `defmulti` for each name instead of repeating the `defmulti` calls. I tried this:

```
(doseq [m '(amount bottles pronoun action pred)]
  (defmulti m identity))
```

However, when I do that it seems as though the `defmulti` does not have the proper effect, as when I later use `defmethod` for any of multimethod names, I get an error such as:

```
(defmethod amount 0 [n] "whatever")

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: amount in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

Is it possible to iterate over a list of symbols or names and call `defmulti` for each of them, and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Since `defmulti` is a macro it gets the symbol `m` as its first argument and not the bound value in the `doseq`. What the `doseq` is actually doing is just defining the multimethod `m` a bunch of times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a macro that wraps over `defmulti` and does the required thing:

```
(defmacro defidmulti [names]
  `(do ~@(for [m names]
           `(defmulti ~m identity))))

(defidmulti [amount bottles pronoun action pred])
```